# Get good @font-face fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

do you know some good sites within good fonts that could be used in websites with font-face?
There are some sites I know, but I search for fonts that I can use in "commercial projects" and they should be licensed optimally under MIT or (New) BSD?

Comment: Is there some kind of @font-face list somewhere?

Comment: Is `@font-face` reliable, or should you still be using sIFR? http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com), they have ready made `@font-face` kits that you can just drop in place.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

http://fontdeck.com/ (Coming soon!)

http://www.fontspring.com/ (Small fee, but good selection)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Typekit](http://typekit.com/) or [Web Fonts](http://www.webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=Fonts_available_for_%40font-face_embedding).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.myfonts.com/

Some fonts are available for free with a license which permits commercial reuse. Their WhatTheFont tool is also useful for identifying fonts you like in existing works.

Answer (score 0):

First place to look is [the Open Font Library](http://openfontlibrary.org/media/view/media/fonts): they have probably the biggest range of freely licensed fonts out there, organised with tags.  Googling for {sil free font license} will give you pointers, as well.

Check out [typoasis](http://moorstation.org/typoasis): there are some sublime fonts if you look around the site.  Free as in beer, not speech.

Look around at the classic fonts by Zapf: some are freely licensed, and there's quite a range.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any site except google that provides a library that u can link to directly in your css file?
 like google
 `@font-face {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/font?kit=YDAoLskQQ5MOAgvHUQCcLdXn3cHbFGWU4T2HrSN6JF4') format('truetype');
}`